# How to getinput stream and display it in textArea?

Tags: java, swing, io, stream, jtextarea

I am sending a stream to my client. How can I read that stream in the client line by line, into a text area in my client?

My server code for sending data:

public class Server extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
public Server() 
{
    int server=5555;
    initComponents();
}




    jRadioButton1.setText("a");
    jRadioButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
        {
            jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jRadioButton2.setText("b");
    jRadioButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
        {
            jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jRadioButton3.setText("c");
    jRadioButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
        {
            jRadioButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jRadioButton4.setText("d");
    jRadioButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
        {
            jRadioButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });


    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setText("SEND");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
        {
             Greedy gg=new Greedy();
             gg.greedy();
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });


    jMenu1.setText("OPEN FILE");
    jMenu1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
        {
            OPEN(evt);

        }
    });

    jMenuItem3.setText("OPEN");
    jMenuItem3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
        {
             String cwd=System.getProperty("user.dir");
            JFileChooser jfc=new JFileChooser(cwd);

             Component frame = null;
            if (jfc.showOpenDialog(frame) !=JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
             return;


             File f = jfc.getSelectedFile();


             try {
                content1(f.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


             readin(f.toString(), jTextArea1);  
        }
    });

private void readin(String string, JTextArea jTextArea12) 
{
    try 
            {

                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(string);
                    jTextArea1.read(fr, null);
                    fr.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    System.err.println(e);
                }

}



private void EXIT(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                      
    System.exit(0); 
}                     

private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{



}

private void jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{

            }

private void jRadioButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{


            }


private void jRadioButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{

}


private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 


    {
```

hello();
        }

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{

          java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            new Server().setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("SERVER IS STARTED.....");
        }
    });

    int port=5000;
    while(true)
    {
       try

    {
    ServerSocket ser=new ServerSocket(port+10);

    System.out.println("CLIENT A IS CONNECTED");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
       try
    {
    ServerSocket ser=new ServerSocket(port+20);

    ser.accept();

    System.out.println("CLIENT B IS CONNECTED");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
       try
    {
    ServerSocket ser=new ServerSocket(port+30);

    ser.accept();

    System.out.println("CLIENT C IS CONNECTED");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
       try
    {
    ServerSocket ser=new ServerSocket(port+40);

    ser.accept();

    System.out.println("CLIENT D IS CONNECTED");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    }
}

public void hello()

 {



     try
     {
     FileReader buf=new FileReader("e:\\buffer.txt");

     int port=5010;
     try
     {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ServerSocket ser=new ServerSocket(port);
        Socket soc=ser.accept();
        BufferedReader toclient=new BufferedReader(buf);
        DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println(dos.toString());

        dos.flush();
        dos.close();




    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         System.out.println(e+"BUFFER IS EMPTY");
     }

 }




 public void content1(String s) throws IOException { 
     try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));
             PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(new File("e:\\buffer.txt"))) {
         for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
             pr.println(line);
         }
     }
```

}

}

Client code:

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
  public class NodeA extends javax.swing.JFrame 
  {


public JLabel sys=new JLabel();



public NodeA() 
{

    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void initComponents() {




    jLabel1.setText("NODE A");


    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);


    jButton1.setText("CONNECT");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
        {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);

        }
    });

    jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); 
    jButton2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 51));
    jButton2.setText("OFFLOAD DATA");

    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
        {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "B", "C", "D" }));
    jComboBox2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {


        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
        {
            jComboBox2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setText("SELECT NODE TO OFFLOAD");

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{


  try
  {
  Socket client=new Socket("localhost",5010);

  if(client.isConnected())
  {
      System.out.println("SERVER ACCEPTS CONNECTION");
  }

  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      System.out.println("SERVER IS BUSY.......");
  }
}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{

}

private void jComboBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{

}

public void data()
{

     DataInputStream is;
     BufferedReader bsr=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));



}
```

}

I want to read the server stream, and display the data in my client text area one line at a time. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Are you getting an error?

Comment: No. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Where is your code attempt to do this? How isn't it working? Where are you stuck? So far what you've posted isn't an answerable question but rather a code dump. Please try to improve this lest it get closed as being unaswerable. Also, you don't want to ignore exceptions.

Comment: hello Hovercraft do I have to post full code?

Comment: @ankitaloveroses There is no need to post the whole code. Post a sample code that shows the problem. Such that together we can solve the problem.

Comment: Best to post a small compilable program that tries to solve the problem but that contains just enough code to do this and to compile and run, but no code unrelated to the problem, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FileReader b = new FileReader("read.txt");
jTextArea.read(b, "read.txt");  // we're done!
```

See docs. for [`JTextComponent.(Reader,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) for details.